# Date displaying in weird way when adding milliseconds

Tags: c#

So in my application I extract data from a database and then extract it to a csv file and I say what I want under each columns like so:

```
public List<ExtractDocument> GetExtractDocuments(List<Guid>ItemDetailIds)
{
    var items = GetExtractData(ItemDetailIds);

    return items.Select().Select(item => new ExtractDocument
    {
        ItemDetailId = item.Field<Guid>("ItemDetailID"),
        ItemNumber = item.Field<string>("Number"),
        ItemTitle = item.Field<string>("Title"),    
        ItemRevision = item.Field<string>("RevisionNumber"),
        ActionType = item.Field<string>("Action"),
        ActionedBy = item.Field<string>("ActionedBy"),
        ActionedDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("ActionedDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        Comment = item.Field<string>("Comment"),
        TaskType = item.Field<string>("TaskType"),
        StartDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("StartDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        CompletedDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("CompletedDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        Status = item.Field<string>("Status"),
        Outcome = item.Field<string>("Outcome"),
        ActionerName = item.Field<string>("TaskActionedBy"),
        DateActioned = item.Field<DateTime?>("ActionDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        ActionTaken = item.Field<string>("TaskAction"),
        TaskComment = item.Field<string>("TaskComment"),
        Link = item.Field<string>("URL")
    }).ToList();

}
```

This is working but when I open up the csv file and look under the date columns such as "ActionedDate" the date is showing up in a weird way, for example one of the values should be showing as:  03/03/2022  09:07:46 but it is showing in the field as:07:46.3, why is it doing this and how I can prevent that from happening? it doesn't do this for all the fields but it does for the majority

Comment: Open it up where? If opening up in Excel you are subject to whatever heuristics Excel uses for detecting the format and whether or not to display it as a time or a date.

Comment: When you call `ToString` passing the date format, you're passing `fff` which are milliseconds. Sometimes you use : separator and sometimes .

Comment: yeah I just realised, complete face palm moment, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this was a face palm moment, just realised I had the format written as: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" when it should be "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", changing it from ss.fff to ss:fff, fixed the issue